# Get all validators on the network, not just the active ones

Tags: polkadot-js, validator

I want to be able to get all the validators on the network, not just the active ones.

`api.query.session.validators()` only gets validators in the active set, how can I get every validator in existence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It might be `api.query.staking.validators()`. But this is a map. You might need to iterate it.

Comment: To complete this answer:

```const entries = await api.query.staking.validators.entries();
const validators = entries.map(([key]) => {
    return key.args.map((k) => k.toHuman());
});```

Answer (score 0):

Completing @AurevoirXavier's answer, the plan is to add this functionality to [API Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar) once [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/pull/1045) is merged.